# Not able to read Sharepoint list items which has blanks in its headers

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am using Sharepoint online to fetch the data from the list. For that I have written below code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential


baseurl = 'https://my.org.com'
basesite = '/teams/ia/Powerappsdatabase/' # every share point has a home.
siteurl = baseurl + basesite
sp_list = "HCFM_Projects"
ctx = ClientContext(siteurl).with_credentials(UserCredential("id@org.com", "password"))
sp_lists = ctx.web.lists
s_list = sp_lists.get_by_title(sp_list)
l_items = s_list.get_items()
ctx.load(l_items)
ctx.execute_query()

for item in l_items:
    print(item.properties['Title'], item.properties['Owner'], item.properties["Status"])
```

For the headers in the sharepoint list which contains like single word in header it is populating values but which headers have space in it like "Project ID", "Process Owner". It is giving error
`KeyError: 'Project ID'`.

Can somebody help me to know how we can get values for those headers which have space in their names or underscore(i tried to replace space with underscore still not working) or can we print `l_items` to know how it is saving column headers with space or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got the answer for it. If you have space or underscore in headers just write without space in header for example:-

```
for item in l_items:
    print(item.properties['ProjectID'], item.properties['ProcessOwner'])
```

This worked for me.